# Inequality Word Problem Help Me Please

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, arithmetic

Use the following breakdown to compute a student's grade:
        $20\%$ for the midterm
        $55\%$ for the test average
        $25\%$ for the final exam

The student wants at least a B for the course. This means she needs a course grade of greater than or equal to an $80$. She earned an $84$ on the midterm and a $75$ for the test average. What does she need on the final exam to get at least a B for the course?

$$80 \leq \frac{84 + 75 + x.25}{3}?$$

Must write inequality, solve the inequality and answer with a sentence.

Comment: This isn't a place where we answer homework questions, the goal is to help you find the correct answer.  Can you show what work you've done?  Nonetheless, welcome to stackexchange!

Comment: i dont understand how to write the inequality its not my homework. i would like to learn to solve the problem.

Comment: Thats perfect.  So a great way to get more help is to show what work you've already done on the problem, what you've tried.  If you show us that, it is easier for us to help you.

Comment: i just added that in a comment below

Comment: @hopeless i can't see the comment showing what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that the student's grade includes $100$ scores:

- The score for the midterm (called $x$) is counted $20$ times
- The score for the test average (called $y$) is counted $55$ times
- The score for the final exam (called $z$) is counted $25$ times

Then the overall average of the student is $\frac{20x+55y+25z}{100}$.

For this specific problem, we need to solve $\frac{84\times 20+ 75\times 55+ 25z}{100}\ge 80$.

Then we should have $5805+25z\ge 8000 \Rightarrow25z\ge8000-5805=2195\Rightarrow z\ge87.8$

You can make the conclusion from here.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: As you are new here, you can click the checkmark below the down arrow of an answer to mark it as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

They got $84\%$ of $20$ points for the midterm and $75\%$ of $55$ points for the test average.  How many more points are needed?  What fraction of $25$ is that?

Comment: 80 <= 84 + 75 + x.25 / 3 ? all of them on the right over 3

Comment: No, you did not account for the weighting.  Getting $84\%$ of $20$ points results in $0.84 \cdot 20=16.8$ points.  You never used the grades received in your calculation.